# How to run a file with .MVC extension?

Tags: extension, mvc

so I downloaded Zinrelo, and now I am trying to run it but it has exactly one file which has the extension of .MVC
how can I open it?

Comment: `.mvc` is typically associated with ASP.NET stuff (or similar), as far as I am aware. You probably need a web server with ASP.NET capabilities (IIS on Windows, e.g. Apache with Mono on Linux).

Comment: refer this may it help you.https://www.filemagic.com/en/video-files/mvc-file-extension/4-easy-ways-to-open-mvc-files/